# If a company is using Microsoft Outlook, are its emails encrypted by default?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Does Outlook use any default encryption or can anyone intercept emails from Outlook unless you specifically enable encryption?

Comment: Outlook [program] is only an email client, not an email service, with the default encryption using SSL and/or TLS, depending on the mail server. One way to ensure end to end encryption, without 3rd party access [server admins], would be to use [Gpg4Win](https://www.gpg4win.org/), which uses an Outlook Add-in that can auto-encrypt emails prior to sending. Many, if not most, businesses using a private email server often encrypt their emails via an employee's SSL cert credentials _(KU: `digitalSignature`, `keyEncipherment` or `keyAgreement` | EKU: `emailProtection`)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transmission of Outlook Email (company or non-company) is encrypted using the default settings in Outlook Send / Receive settings.

The database (Exchange or PST file) is proprietary but not encrypted. A person with correct credentials can export an email file and read it on another machine.

I have not seen a setting to encrypt the database. The Exchange setup itself is secure.

Comment: One way to encrypt the `.pst` database would be via [GPG](https://www.gpg4win.org/), however it would need to be decrypted before use and re-encrypted after Outlook is closed _(this could be automated via a Task that monitors Events for Outlook closing and auto-runs a script to encrypt)_, however this wouldn't work with accounts requiring `.ost` databases _(Gmail, Hotmail/Outlook, etc.)_, as they're simply cache files and not a standalone database.